# Should I wait for Spring to have my backyard deck painted?

Tags: patio

I need my deck painted. Should I wait until next spring or should I have it done during the month of October and November before winter?

Comment: Are you in NY, as your user name suggests?

Comment: Can you identify the current condition of the deck.  Is the current paint solid enough to protect the wood.

Comment: I'm worried about the wood. There are cracks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with painting the deck this fall.  It typically has dry days with low humidity depending where you are in NY.  Just make sure the humidity is low so that the paint can dry properly.  This will get the wood protected for winter.  Just check the weather and plan well.

Comment: Except that freezing may occur overnight, which can affect wet paint.